UEFI Boot order not changing(windows 11 on Hp 15-dw3003ni Laptop
I am trying to install windows 11 on SSD m2 NVMe using USB to my i5-1135G7, Under UEFI BOOT ORDER I can toggle but only OS Boot Manager can be selected. I tested the USB is working on other hp laptop. I even formated the HDD to try on it but it's same. The laptop was working fine but slower as it had no SSD. I've included the picture


This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Shut down completely. Press and hold the key to change boot order (F9 on some HP's). Select the USB drive. If it does not show, then it's not formatted so that PC recognizes it.

As above. If you have no OS installed the only action you can take is to boot from any OS installation media.
